# Kubuntu 13.10 - Left click causes scrolling

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I'm running Kubuntu 13.10 on a Toshiba Satellite, and left clicking on the physical buttons below the touchpad causes a single tick of downward scrolling along with the expected function of the left click. This is not a major detriment, but it is thoroughly annoying, nonetheless.

I've tried everything short of editing the system's .conf files.

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adjusting the Mouse settings?

System Settings > Keyboard / Mouse > Mouse > Buttons > Left-Click > Primary Click

(sorry if this isn't the exact order, not on my KDE box ATM)

If you can't click, I recommend mucking around in X configs. You can look online for X documentations. Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations